# twitter bootstrap Tab content is not showing until i open Firebug in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with Twitter bootstrap Tabs.
Actually i have Images gallery with Carousel in each tab, There are only two tabs for now.
When page loaded active tab work perfectly as expected but when i clicked on other tab its content is not showing. but when i click for open Firebug in mozilla its showing.

Can anyone help me in this regard here is link http://javendesign.com/projects/htb/portfolio/104-w120th-st-manhattan/
Please check it and Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doubt this helps at all but it looks like it's actually the window resize that is triggering a script to execute and cause the contents to appear.

Comment: Do you think it could be a CSS issue, Website is not responsive i can Give elements fixed height and width. Please Suggest.